# Issue getting VS2010 to recognize System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a project where I'm beginning to use LINQ for the first time and wanted to use the CopyToDataTable function. I know to use it I must add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtentions, which I've done, here's the statements.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.DataSetExtensions
```

The last line gets error: "the namespace or type selected doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found".

Here's the linq code I'm using, which gets error "'CopyToDataTable' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)'."

```
            Dim qrySpec = _
            From tblSpecs In dtAllResults.AsEnumerable()
            Where tblSpecs.Field(Of String)("SPEC_DESC")
            Order By tblSpecs.Item("SPEC_DESC")
            Select tblSpecs.Item("SPEC_DESC") Distinct

            Dim dt As DataTable = qrySpec.CopyToDataTable()
```

I'm currently running full .Net Framework 4.0 and have verified the reference has been added and it's version is 4.0.

Only thing I can find in my research is perhaps I need to revert down to .Net Framework 3.5, the file path is too long, or the SQL Server's .Net framework is pre-3.5.  I really need to stay in 4.0 and I've tried copying the dll to a new/shorter path and referencing it there.  Neither have worked.  I am in the process of getting with the DBA's on the SQL Server info.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is not a namespace.

The `CopyToDataTable` is indeed in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` but the namespace is just `System.Data`.

Edit:

Also, `CopyToDataTable` is defined as this:

```
public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : DataRow;
```

Your IEnumerable from your query must be of type `DataRow`. So, you would either need to  somehow return your results as DataRow from the query.

The current issue is that you are not selecting your row, you are using the `Item` method to select a set of Objects.

**EDIT2**:

If all you are after is a DataTable with distinct `SPEC_DESC` in it, then perhaps this would do:

```
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    table2.Columns.Add("SPEC_DESC", typeof(string));

    foreach (var desc in (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                select (string) row["SPEC_DESC"]).Distinct())
        {
                table2.Rows.Add(desc);
        }
```

Comment: gotcha. I removed that statement.  Any idea as to why it still giving me the ""'CopyToDataTable' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)'." error?

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  I at least now know it's the LINQ query setup and not the reference.  First day working with it, I'll research more and figure it out.  Thanks for steering me in the rigth direction.